# Leer datos completos de un json

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando leer el siguiente json el problema que no logro encontrar leer toda la estructura completa.

Json:

```
[
{
    "fecha_fin": [
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018"
    ],
    "dias": [
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:"
    ],
    "fecha_inicio": [
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018"
    ],
    "valor": [
        "1478.59",
        "1503.74",
        "1618.08",
        "1751.47",
        "1752.99",
        "1857.20",
        "1857.20",
        "2068.17",
        "2455.23",
        "2493.70",
        "2631.47",
        "2719.68",
        "2775.99",
        "2903.70",
        "3058.29",
        "3175.92",
        "3717.00"
    ],
    "recogida_devolucion": [
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro",
        "Bariloche Centro"
    ],
    "modelo": [
        "Ford Ka SE \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Gol \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Corsa Classic \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Prisma \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Fiat Palio \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Gol \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Nissan Versa \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Up \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Up \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Peugeot 408 \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Nissan March \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Renault Clio \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Prisma \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Prisma \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Classic \n                        ",
        "\n                        "
    ],
    "compania": [
        "Localiza",
        "Rentacar Argentina",
        "Rentacar Argentina",
        "Rentacar Argentina",
        "Localiza",
        "Alamo",
        "Alamo",
        "Rentacar Argentina",
        "Alamo",
        "Budget",
        "Avis",
        "Alamo",
        "Budget",
        "Avis",
        "Budget",
        "Avis",
        "Dubrovnik"
    ]
},
{
    "fecha_fin": [
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018"
    ],
    "dias": [
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:",
        "Precio por 1 día:"
    ],
    "fecha_inicio": [
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018",
        "10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018"
    ],
    "valor": [
        "1478.59",
        "1600.55",
        "1600.55",
        "1600.55",
        "1638.65",
        "1676.77",
        "1676.77",
        "1711.45",
        "1715.26",
        "1752.99",
        "1752.99",
        "1752.99",
        "1791.11",
        "1825.78",
        "1828.83",
        "1857.20",
        "1857.20",
        "1959.17",
        "2096.00",
        "2134.11",
        "2248.82",
        "2275.87",
        "2324.65",
        "2404.63",
        "2455.23",
        "2493.70",
        "2540.73",
        "2631.47",
        "2676.85",
        "2719.68",
        "2775.99",
        "2846.27",
        "2903.70",
        "3058.29",
        "3175.92",
        "3717.00",
        "3891.20",
        "4571.21",
        "6384.59",
        "7291.27"
    ],
    "recogida_devolucion": [
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto",
        "Bariloche Aeropuerto"
    ],
    "modelo": [
        "Ford Ka SE \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Onix \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Corsa \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Gol \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Gol \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Classic \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Fiat Palio \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Gol \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Fiat Palio \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Prisma \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Fiat Siena \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Gol \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Gol \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Corsa Classic \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Classic \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Fiat Palio \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Gol \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios Sedan \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Aveo \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Nissan Versa \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Up \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Aveo \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Volkswagen Up \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Peugeot 408 \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Nissan March \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Renault Logan \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Renault Clio \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Prisma \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Prisma \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Classic \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Chevrolet Celta \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Fiat Palio \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Toyota Etios \n                        ",
        "\n                        ",
        "Peugeot 408 \n                        ",
        "\n                        "
    ],
    "compania": [
        "Localiza",
        "Hertz",
        "Hertz",
        "Europcar",
        "Europcar",
        "Europcar",
        "Keddy By Europcar",
        "Rentacar Argentina",
        "Keddy By Europcar",
        "Localiza",
        "Keddy By Europcar",
        "Europcar",
        "Europcar",
        "Rentacar Argentina",
        "Europcar",
        "Alamo",
        "Alamo",
        "Rentacar Argentina",
        "Hertz",
        "Europcar",
        "Keddy By Europcar",
        "Rentacar Argentina",
        "Europcar",
        "Europcar",
        "Alamo",
        "Budget",
        "Keddy By Europcar",
        "Avis",
        "Europcar",
        "Alamo",
        "Budget",
        "VDS Rent a Car",
        "Avis",
        "Budget",
        "Avis",
        "Dubrovnik",
        "National",
        "National",
        "National",
        "National"
    ]
}
```

]

Codigo:

```
with open(fstat, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
                        distros_dict = json.load(f)

                        for distro in distros_dict:
                                compania = distro['compania'][0]
                                valor = distro['valor'][0]
                                dias = distro['dias'][0]
                                modelo = distro['modelo'][0]
                                recogida = distro['recogida_devolucion'][0]
                                fecha_inicio = distro['fecha_inicio'][0]
                                fecha_fin = distro['fecha_fin'][0]
```

Si intento leerlo con el codigo anterior solo lee la primer fila de cada seccion del json, y termina.

O sea de Bariloche Centro toma un registro y luego leo otro de Bariloche Aeropuerto y finaliza, como puedo leerlo completo y en orden para que cada registro este asociado correctamente a los datos.

Edit:

Necesito que la salida sea que de la estructura que contiene Bariloche Centro tome el primer dato de fecha_fin luego dias y asi sucesivamente con el resto hasta compania y valla itinerando con los datos de acuerdo a su orden el primero, el segundo etc.. una vez finalizado todo de Bariloche Centro pase a Bariloche Aeropuerto y suceda lo mismo.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De lo que entiendo de la pregunta es que quieres usar todos los registros en las variables.

Por ejemplo:
En la variable compania tener todos los registros de compañía, para el primero los 16 y para el segundo los 39.

Al utilizar el [0] únicamente estás accediendo al primer registro de cada atributo. Quita el [0] para que puedas registrar todos. Además estás usando las mismas variables dentro del for, eso hará que en cada loop los valores de los registros cambien.

Si lo que deseas es usar el elemento [i] y agruparlo en una variable para cada atributo correspondiente, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as f:
    distros_dict = json.load(f)
    datos = []
    dato = {}
    for distro in distros_dict:
        pprint(len(distro['compania'])-1)       
        i=0
        while i < len(distro['compania']):
            dato['compania'] = distro['compania'][i]        
            dato['valor'] = distro['valor'][i]
            dato['dias'] = distro['dias'][i]
            dato['modelo'] = distro['modelo'][i]
            dato['recogida_devolucion'] = distro['recogida_devolucion'][i]
            dato['fecha_inicio'] = distro['fecha_inicio'][i]
            dato['fecha_fin'] = distro['fecha_fin'][i]
            i+=1
            datos.append(dato)
pprint(datos)
```

El print se verá como lo siguiente:

```
{'compania': 'National',
 'dias': 'Precio por 1 dÃ\xada:',
 'fecha_fin': '10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018',
 'fecha_inicio': '10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018',
 'modelo': '\n                        ',
 'recogida_devolucion': 'Bariloche Aeropuerto',
 'valor': '7291.27'},
{'compania': 'National',
 'dias': 'Precio por 1 dÃ\xada:',
 'fecha_fin': '10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018',
 'fecha_inicio': '10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018',
 'modelo': '\n                        ',
 'recogida_devolucion': 'Bariloche Aeropuerto',
 'valor': '7291.27'},
{'compania': 'National',
 'dias': 'Precio por 1 dÃ\xada:',
 'fecha_fin': '10:00 21 de noviembre de 2018',
 'fecha_inicio': '10:00 20 de noviembre de 2018',
 'modelo': '\n                        ',
 'recogida_devolucion': 'Bariloche Aeropuerto',
 'valor': '7291.27'},...
```

Saludos

Comment: Si quito el [0] me trae todos los datos por clave, y lo que necesito es que itinere de una a uno, es lo que no eh podido resolver

Comment: He editado la respuesta, creo que es lo que necesitas.